# Input text html with dynamic zeros

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a mask for my html using javascript. I am using the following code but I did not succeed:

```
function valorMax(v){
  v=v.replace(/\D/g,"")
        if (v.length <= 20) { 
          v=v.replace(/(\d{17})(\d)/,"$10000000000000.$2")
        }
        return v
}
```

I need in the text field when entering a currency value, it automatically completes with 0 (zero) and separates the cents with the. (dot), with a total value of 19 digits

Ex: Enter 100 and the value in the text field becomes 00000000000000100.00

Ex: Enter 10.25 and the value in the text field becomes 0000000000000010.25

Ex: enter 1.30 and the value in the text field becomes 0000000000000001.30

Can someone help me?
Thank you very much.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `toFixed` with `padStart` methods to achive this.

```js
const padWithZeros = (number) => number.toFixed(2).toString().padStart(19, 0)

console.log(padWithZeros(100))
console.log(padWithZeros(10.25))
console.log(padWithZeros(1.3))
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this you can achieve solution without RegEx.

```js
var input = '10.2'
function formatNumber(input){
  var wholeNumber = input.split('.')[0]
  var decimalNumber = input.split('.')[1] || ''
  if (decimalNumber.length < 2){
   decimalNumber = decimalNumber.concat(...new Array(2 - decimalNumber.length).fill(0))
  }
  if (wholeNumber.length < 17){
   wholeNumber = ''.concat(...new Array(17 - wholeNumber.length).fill(0), wholeNumber)
  }
  console.log(`${wholeNumber}.${decimalNumber}`)
}
formatNumber(input)
```

Answer (score 0):

[`.toLocaleString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) special purpose is to convert strings into language sensitive currency formats.

```js
// U.S. Currency
const us = (number, digits) => {
  return number.toLocaleString('en-US', {
    minimumIntegerDigits: digits,
    useGrouping: false,
    style: 'currency',
    currency: 'USD'
  });
}

// Generic Currency
const xx = (number, digits) => {
  return number.toLocaleString(undefined, {
    minimumIntegerDigits: digits,
    useGrouping: false,
    minimumFractionDigits: 2,
    maximumFractionDigits: 2
  });
}

console.log(us(111.3, 19));
console.log(us(2500, 19));
console.log(us(.02, 19));

console.log(xx(111.3, 19));
console.log(xx(2500, 19));
console.log(xx(.02, 19));
```